# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I have looked at similar questions but they say that this happens because the js is called before the html but I think that in my code the element is called once all the html is loaded I believe.

```
<table id="UserCards">
  <tr>
    <th width=20%><strong>Card Holder</strong></th>
    <th width=20%><strong>Card Number</strong></th>
    <th width=10%><strong>Expiry Date</strong></th>
    <th width=10%><strong>CVC</strong></th>
    <th width="5%"></th>
  </tr>
  {% for row in rows %}
      <tr>
        <td id="name">{{ row['CardName']}}</td>
        <td id="number">****************</td>
        <td class="realnumber" style="display:none;">{{ row['CardNo'] }}</td>
        <td id="date">{{ row['CardExpDate'] }}</td>
        <td id="code">***</td>
        <td id="realcode" style="display:none;">{{ row['CardSecretCode'] }}</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="delete-row" onclick="deleteThis(this)"><span class="fas fa-trash-alt"></span></a></td>
      </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

```
function deleteThis(obj){
      var cardnumber = $(obj).siblings('.realnumber')[0].textContent;
      $(obj).closest('tr').remove();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{{ url_for('deleterow') }}",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ number: cardnumber }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
          window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/Drunkfy/Home/Paymentdetails';;
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: You appear to be removing the `<tr>` with `$(obj).closest('tr').remove()` so that would mean the element within that `<tr>` with `id="realnumber"` would also be removed. Do you see the problem there?

Comment: Is it just me, or is anyone else concerned with the rendering of full card details in to the DOM here?

Comment: It will not deal with real data, it is just for a project I need to do for school. The rendering would require more advanced knowledge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line of the `deleteThis` method is deleting the entire wrapping `tr` element, which will delete elements inside of it too. So - if you only have 1 item in the list - by the time it hits that second line of code there **IS NO** `td` with an `id` of `realnumber` anymore.

Try moving the second line up one so you retrieve it before you remove the tr.

```
  var cardnumber = document.getElementById('realnumber').textContent;
  $(obj).closest('tr').remove();
```

Additionally, you're using `id` on elements that are repeated from a list, which means you'll likely have multiple `<td>` elements on the page with the same `id` of `realnumber`. You should fix this, otherwise the `document.getElementById` will *always* return you the very first `realnumber` `td` on the page regardless of which one you're deleting.

Consider switching it to a class and then using jquery to find it:

```
  var cardnumber = $(obj).parent().siblings('.realnumber')[0].textContent;
  $(obj).closest('tr').remove();
```

Comment: maybe, but how did you know that the mentioned `tr`  was targeted ?!

Comment: The first line of code inside the method uses `this` (the `a` element) and `closest` to find the first parent that matches the css selector of `tr`. It then calls remove on it. So, it seems that the `a` element - on click - will seek and destroy it's containing table row.

Comment: he used `$(obj).closest('tr').remove()` or am I seeing an unedited version of his code!
again it probably is, that he's removing the entire `tr` element but until you know what `obj` is
or see the method call you can't say for sure

Comment: You can see the method call at line 17 in the first code block in the question. :) `onclick="deleteThis(this)"`

Comment: holly mama, the devil inline, I stand corrected! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although I have done what you said and I use ```var cardnumber = $(obj).siblings('.realnumber')[0].textContent;``` I get  Can't read property of undefined. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: @metrallador10 Have changed the `id="realnumber"` in your html to `class="realnumber"`?

Comment: Yes I have I tried removing the  [0] and that does not give me the error but gives me an empty array as result

Comment: @AndyJames I have edited the code with my current version

Comment: @metrallador10 I see what I did. The `.realnumber` `td` is not a `sibling` of the clicked `a`. It's an... "uncle" xD. Just get the `.parent()` first and then search for it's siblings. I've updated the answer.